# Prove statement about projection (linear map)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am working on the following problem and do am not sure how best to approach it.

Let $U$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and $p, q: U \to U$ be linear maps.
Assume $p + q = \text{id}_U$ and $pq = 0$.
Let $K$ = $\ker(p)$ and $L = \ker(q)$.
Prove $p^2 = p$.

From the given information, I know that $\ker(pq) = U \implies$ the nullity of $pq$ is equal to $\dim(U) \implies$ the rank of $pq$ is equal to $0 \implies pq$ is not invertible.
However, I don't know if these observations are necessary for me to solve the problem.
I would appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply $p$ to the equation
$$p+q = \mathrm{id}_U$$
To get
$$p(p+q) = p^2 + pq = p$$
an then $p^2 = p$. Similarly, by appling $q$ from the right, you get
$$(p+q)q = pq + q^2 = q$$
so $q^2 = q$.
To show that $qp = 0$ now, take a look at
$$(p+q)^2 - (p+q)$$

Comment: Another part of the problem is to prove that $qp = 0$.  Can this be done in a similar way to the hint that you gave in your answer?

Comment: @CKKOY Yes, prove $q^2=q$ first an then look at $(p+q)^2 = \mathrm{id}_U$

Answer (score 2):

$$p+q=I \Rightarrow q=I-p$$

$$
pq=p(I-p)=0 \Rightarrow p-p^2=0 \Rightarrow p=p^2$$

Comment: This seems intuitively correct to me.  Would you be able to give a reason for why such algebra on linear maps is allowed?  I have never manipulated linear maps in such a way before.

Comment: The law of associativity holds, the law of distributivity holds... actually, this is so simple it doesn't even use associativity.